# Foreach function to show value for blade page

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

im currently on clustering project now.. can anyone help me how to foreach to display the value of the array below? im really confused about this array. The table output that I expected like this

```
IP | SOURCE | STATUS CODE | DAY INX | TIME INX | C1 | C2 | CLUSTER
```

3.121.42.61 GET /.aws/credentials HTT   0   1   Cluster

## var_dump array variable

```
[0] => Array
  (
 [162.243.131.5] => Array
                (
                    [GET /manager/html HTTP/1.1] => Array
                        (
                            [404] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 2
                                    [1] => 00
                                )

                        )

                    [0] => 16.492422502471
                    [1] => 9.8488578017961
                    [Cluster] => 1
                )
 [3.121.42.61] => Array
                (
                    [GET /.aws/credentials HTTP/1.1] => Array
                        (
                            [404] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 7
                                    [1] => 00
                                )

                        )

                    [0] => 16.031219541881
                    [1] => 9.0553851381374
                    [Cluster] => 1
                )
    )
```

any advice will be very helpful, thank you.

> code that I have tried

```
           @foreach($total[0] as $vtk=>$vtn)
                <tr>
                <td>{{$vtk}}</td>
            @foreach($vtn as $srk=>$srn)
                <td>{{substr($srk,0,25)}}</td>
            @endforeach
            @endforeach
```

from the code that I have, I can display a column like this

```
IP ADDRESS |              SOURCE         | STATUSCODE | DAY INDEX | TIME INDEX | C1 | C2 | CLUSTER
3.121.42.61| GET /.aws/credentials HTT   |      0     |     1     | Cluster    |
```

Comment: "_Help me_" or "_Code this for me_"? Can you paste the code you already have?

Comment: Hi @kerbholz thanks for the reply, sorry i edited it.